# Equivalent statement of $2^\text{nd}$ Sylow Theorem in the proof: a normal $p$-subgroup contained in all Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I stumbled upon this nice and neat proof about  how a normal $p$-subgroup contained in all Sylow $p$-subgroups.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Normal_p-Subgroup_contained_in_All_Sylow_p-Subgroups

But in the step where second Sylow  theorem  is recalled, the proof states the second Sylow theorem as:

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of the finite group $G$.

Let $Q$ be any $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Then $Q$ is a subset of a conjugate of $P$.

But Wiki as most literature states this  as: All  Sylow $p$  subgroups are conjugate to each other. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems.

How this two statements of second Sylow theorem are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the alternative statement of the second theorem.  If $Q$ is large enough to be a Sylow subgroup, then assuming it's contained in a conjugate of $P$ means (since they have the same size) that it must *be* a conjugate of $P$.

Conversely, if all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate to one another and $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup (not necessarily Sylow), then $Q$ is contained in *some* Sylow subgroup and that Sylow subgroup is conjugate to $P$, so $Q$ is contained in a conjugate of $P$.

Comment: For the converse your  are using that a  $Q$  $p-$ subgroup is contained in a Sylow subgroup but that is what Im intending to prove in the link. So you will be using what you need to prove in the proof @Robert_Shore

Comment: @Cos: You said you are trying to prove that a normal $p$-subgroup is contained in *every* Sylow $p$-subgroup; that's different. And the statement being proven is that if $P$ is a fixed Sylow $p$-subgroup, and $Q$ is any $p$-subgroup, then $Q$ is contained in a conjugate of $P$. Neither is the statement that a $p$-subgroup is contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Your two sources have different definitions of Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Wikipedia's is that they are maximal $p$-subgroups under inclusion, so the statement that any $p$-subgroup is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup is clear. Then the statement of the first part of Sylow's theorem is that the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is $p^n$, where $|G|=p^na$ with $p\nmid a$.

Proof Wiki's is that a Sylow $p$-subgroup is a $p$-subgroup of order $p^n$, where $|G|$ is as above. Then the first part is that Sylow $p$-subgroups exist. But inclusion of $p$-subgroups is not obvious from this definition, and so that must form part of the statement.

In general, the first part of Sylow's theorem states that Sylow $p$-subgroups always exist and have order $p^n$ (this is a good conclusion with either definition, it's just that one of the two statements is clear). The second part is that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, and that every $p$-subgroup is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup (one part is clear for one definition). The third is that the number is $1$ modulo $p$.

Sylow's theorem, in part, asserts that the two definitions of Sylow $p$-subgroups are the same.

Comment: I think the question is about two statements of Sylow's second (for finite groups): (i) If $P$ and $Q$ are two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, then $P$ and $Q$ are conjugate; and (ii) If $P$ is a given Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, and $Q$ is any $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $Q$ is contained in a conjugate of $P$. Everything you say is correct, but it seems to be orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My point was that they are not equal, because the definitions of Sylow $p$-subgroups are different in the two statements of Sylow's theorem. You cannot ask how to prove two statements are equivalent if the definitions of the concepts are not equivalent. In order to start, you need to rewrite both statements in terms of the same definitions, and then the OP's question disappears.

Comment: Well, I'm confused. Even with the same definition of Sylow subgroup, the two statements are different; they are *equivalent*, but different. Of course, how you prove them to be equivalent may differ depending on your definition of "Sylow $p$-subgroup" (and on exactly what version of Sylow's first theorem you've proven).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. The OP wants to know how to get that any $p$-subgroup is a subgroup of a Sylow $p$-subgroup. This is part of the definition for one version, but this doesn't follow at all from the fact that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate with the other definition. With the other definition, this extra fact is included as part of Sylow's theorem, and it usually has four parts with that definition, not three.

Comment: We are definitely interpreting the OP differently. I understood the post to be asking why "every $p$-subgroup is a subgroup of a conjugate of a given, fixed, Sylow $p$-subgroup" is equivalent to "any two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate to one another"; and I'm assuming this is done with knowledge of Sylow's first (some version thereof) At least, that's what the post says; perhaps you are trying to address the comment in the other answer, and that's the source of my confusion?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's only equivalent with the definition that a Sylow $p$-subgroup is a maximal $p$-subgroup under inclusion. It is definitely not equivalent using the other definition (except insofar as all true statements are equivalent). So with the fixed order definition, the second theorem must take the form every $p$-subgroup is a subgroup of a conjugate of a fixed Sylow $p$-subgroup. In particular, this implies that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate by taking a different Sylow $p$-subgroup to be your $p$-subgroup.

Comment: With the maximal subgroup definition, you just need to state that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, as then every subgroup is contained in some Sylow, which is then conjugate to a fixed one.